# Different coloured threads using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a `DataFrame` called `plot_data`. It has ~998 rows and 23 rows. I go through the data using this code and creating 3 SubPlots, each displaying a different `Level`

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL23m.png)

```py
fig=plt.figure()

for i in range(0,plot_data.shape[0]):
    if (plot_data["Level"].iloc[i] == "Low"):
        plt.subplot(311)
        plt.plot(plot_data.drop(columns =["Level"]).iloc[i],"green",linewidth=0.6)
        plt.xticks([])
    elif (plot_data["Level"].iloc[i] == "Medium"):
        plt.subplot(312)
        plt.plot(plot_data.drop(columns =["Level"]).iloc[i],"yellow",linewidth=0.6)
        plt.xticks([])
    else :
        plt.subplot(313)
        plt.plot(plot_data.drop(columns =["Level"]).iloc[i],"red",linewidth=0.6)
        plt.xticks([])

plt.show()
```

Instead of every thread having the same color id like to know how to make every thread be a different color than the past one. While i know that multiple threads overlap it would be great to see some variance in the threads.

Answer (score 0):

From the plotting argument just remove color parameter.
Then plt will plot the line on it's on with different color.
Matplotlib by-default has only 10 color for cycling so if you are plotting more than 10 plots you will see colors are being repeated.

If want different color for every thread/line you can use colormap as follows but color will be same among subplots but not within a subplot:

```py
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,len(df))) # create as many division as the no. of rows.
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    if (df[3].iloc[i] == "l"):
        plt.subplot(311)
        plt.plot(df.drop(columns =[3]).iloc[i],color=colors[i],linewidth=0.6)
        plt.xticks([])
    elif (df[3].iloc[i] == "m"):
        plt.subplot(312)
        plt.plot(df.drop(columns =[3]).iloc[i],color=colors[i],linewidth=0.6)
        plt.xticks([])
    else :
        plt.subplot(313)
        plt.plot(df.drop(columns =[3]).iloc[i],color=colors[i],linewidth=0.6)
        plt.xticks([])

plt.show()
```